# Vim highlighting with python recursive definitions

Tags: python, recursion, vim, syntax, highlighting

I use the jellybeans colorscheme for vim. I'm noticing that when writing a recursive function that the name is only highlighted at the beginning of the definition and not within the indentation block:

```
def fact(n):        #'fact' appears yellow
    ...
    return n*fact(n-1) #'fact' appears in white like regular text, variables etc.
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: python syntax bundled in vim doesn't support syntax for func in expression.

Comment: Ok - that seemed to be the only plausible explanation. I did wonder whether there were other solutions though. Thanks.

Comment: Yes there are solutions but requires some work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are solutions but  do you really want that: it can highlight just all your code.

---

Just highlight all what looks like myfunc():

```
:syn match calledFunc /\(\w\|\.\)\+\ze(/
:hi calledFunc ctermfg=Yellow
```

---

Note:

With the syntax priority (`:help syn-priority`) this should do exactely what you want. Because functions definitions like def myfunc(): are considered as keyword (and have higher priority):
see `/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/python.vim`:

```
syn keyword pythonStatement class def nextgroup=pythonFunction skipwhite
syn match   pythonFunction "\%(\%(def\s\|class\s\|@\)\s*\)\@<=\h\%(\w\|\.\)*" contained
HiLink pythonFunction Function
```

an other slow solution can be:

- 1/ Parse the file (and included ?) to get all functions, store them in a list
- 2/ Hightlight these functions